# replace number between two tags javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var input = " <root> <date>1995-03-03</date> <heure>13:33</heure> <day0>2</day0> <day1>0</day1> <day2>0</day2> <no2>1</no2> <pm10>2</pm10> <day0_o3>0</day0_o3> <day1_o3>0</day1_o3> <day2_o3>0</day2_o3> </root>"
```

Suppose i want to update day0 value as 6, then output will be

```
OutPut = " <root> <date>1995-03-03</date> <heure>13:33</heure> <day0>6</day0> <day1>0</day1> <day2>0</day2> <no2>1</no2> <pm10>2</pm10> <day0_o3>0</day0_o3> <day1_o3>0</day1_o3> <day2_o3>0</day2_o3> </root>"
```

Thanks for the response i have fixed this

```
input.replace(/<day0>.*<\/day0>/, '<day0>6</day0>');
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure how you get the input but if its from the DOM,
you can use `document.getElementsByTagName("day0")[0].innerText = "new output";`

please give a bit more details if you meant something else

Answer (score 0):

Using pure javascript you can write something like this:

```
document.querySelector("day0").textContent = "6";
```

If you should support browsers, that do now know about textContent, you can write:

```
document.querySelector("day0").innerText = "6";
```

Do not use innerHTML to replace text to prevent XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write your own little function to look for the tags in the string, assuming the input will always be a string with tags in it.

for example:

```
var replaceValueInTag = (tags, tagName, newValue) => {
    var startTag = `<${tagName}>`;
    var endTag = `</${tagName}>`;

    var indexOfStartTag = tags.indexOf(startTag);
    var indexOfEndTag = tags.indexOf(endTag);

    var value = tags.substring(indexOfStartTag + startTag.length, indexOfEndTag);

    return tags.replace(`${startTag}${value}${endTag}`, `${startTag}${newValue}${endTag}`); 
}

var tags = " <root> <date>1995-03-03</date> <heure>13:33</heure> <day0>2</day0> <day1>0</day1> <day2>0</day2> <no2>1</no2> <pm10>2</pm10> <day0_o3>0</day0_o3> <day1_o3>0</day1_o3> <day2_o3>0</day2_o3> </root>":

replaceValueInTag(tags, 'day0', '6');

// output: 
// <root> <date>1995-03-03</date> <heure>13:33</heure> <day0>6</day0> <day1>0</day1> <day2>0</day2> <no2>1</no2> <pm10>2</pm10> <day0_o3>0</day0_o3> <day1_o3>0</day1_o3> <day2_o3>0</day2_o3> </root>
```